# How to return multiple values from a function & use them in a while loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game and need to return the playerscore & computerscore from the game funcntion to my while loop that is checking whether or not either side has reached a score of 3.

I've tried moving my while loop into the game function but that yielded the same results, and this code currently allows the game to keep going after one side reaches 3 wins.

```js
function computerPlay() {
    let choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
    let choicefix = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    let choice = choicefix.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + choicefix.slice(1);
    return choice;
}

function playerChoice() {
    let guess = window.prompt('Choose: Rock, Paper, or Scissors');
    guess = guess.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + guess.slice(1);
    return guess; 
}

function game(player, computer, playerwins, computerwins) {
    if(player===computer) {
        console.log("This round is a TIE!");
    }
    if(player=='Rock' && computer=='Scissors') {
        console.log(`You chose ${player} and the computer chose ${computer}. You WIN!`);
        playerwins += 1;
    }
    if(player=='Rock' && computer=='Paper') {
        console.log(`You chose ${player} and the computer chose ${computer}. You LOSE!`);
        computerwins += 1;
    }
    if(player=='Paper' && computer=='Rock') {
        console.log(`You chose ${player} and the computer chose ${computer}. You WIN!`);
        playerwins += 1;
    }
    if(player=='Paper' && computer=='Scissors') {
        console.log(`You chose ${player} and the computer chose ${computer}. You LOSE!`);
        computerwins += 1;
    }
    if(player=='Scisssors' && computer=='Paper') {
        console.log(`You chose ${player} and the computer chose ${computer}. You WIN!`);
        playerwins += 1;
    }
    if(player=='Scissors' && computer=='Rock') {
        console.log(`You chose ${player} and the computer chose ${computer}. You LOSE!`);
        computerwins += 1;
    }
    console.log(`Your score: ${playerwins}`);
    console.log(`Computer wins: ${computerwins}`);
    return [playerwins, computerwins]
}

let playerwins = 0;
let computerwins = 0;
let player = playerChoice();
let computer = computerPlay();
while(playerwins < 3 || computerwins < 3) {
        let player = playerChoice();
        let computer = computerPlay();
        game(player, computer, playerwins, computerwins);
        let scores = game();
        playerwins = scores[0];
        computerwins = scores[1];
}
```

Comment: `playerwins < 3 || computerwins < 3` I think you mean AND here, because otherwise `5 < 3 || 1 < 3` is `true`.

Comment: To return multiple values from a function in `JS` you can wrap them in an `Array` or `Object`

Comment: Thanks Vlaz, that worked - I forgot to test for those kind of cases.